why the velocity of the ball is changing in canvas
So I was making brick break game on canvas python, I was able to create a moving ball and a moving
bar and the collision of ball to bar, now I made the code in such a way that if ball goes
down to the bottom of canvas the score deducts and the ball gets deleted and will again appear
at the previous initial position while running the game, the thing is that velocity is fixed
for ball but on its another appearance after falling to down of canvas its velocity varies
or you can say its velocity increases and gives an index error of a list, I couldn't understand
the error or the way the ball behaves, I'm posting code down below so please have a look on it
and I also need help to create motion of ball more consistent like in the actual game
code :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time

score = 0
x_velocity = 30
y_velocity = 20

def left(event):

    if canvas.coords(paddle)[0] < 0:
        canvas.move(paddle, 0,0)
    else:
        canvas.move(paddle, -10,0)

def right(event):

    if canvas.coords(paddle)[2] > 800:
        canvas.move(paddle, 0, 0)
    else:
        canvas.move(paddle, 10,0)

def ball_formation():

    global ball
    ball = canvas.create_oval(150,150,170,170, fill = 'white')
    window.update()
    window.after(300,ball_motion())

def ball_motion():

    global score

    if canvas.coords(ball)[0] <= 0 or canvas.coords(ball)[2] >= 800:
        global x_velocity
        x_velocity = - x_velocity

    elif canvas.coords(ball)[1] <= 0:
        global y_velocity
        y_velocity = - y_velocity

    elif canvas.coords(ball)[1] >= 500: # this is where the ball gets 
                                        # made again
                                        # and somehow its velocity 
                                        # changes
        if score > 200 :
            score-= 200

        else:
            score = 0

        score_label.config(text = 'Score : {}'.format(score))

        canvas.delete(ball)

        window.update()
        window.after(300,ball_formation())


    elif collision_of_ball_with_paddle() is True:
        score += 250
        score_label.config(text = 'Score : {}'.format(score))
    
    canvas.move(ball, x_velocity, y_velocity)
    window.after(300,ball_motion)       

def collision_of_ball_with_paddle():

    if canvas.coords(ball)[2] >= canvas.coords(paddle)[0] and canvas.coords(ball)[2] <= canvas.coords(paddle)[2] and canvas.coords(ball)[3] >= 395:                                    
        global y_velocity                  
        y_velocity = - y_velocity
        return True

    else:
        return False

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Game')
window.geometry('900x600+135+0')

score_label = Label(window, font = ('consolas',40), text = 'Score : {}'.format(score))
score_label.pack(side = 'top')

canvas = Canvas(window, width = 800, height = 500, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack()

paddle = canvas.create_rectangle(10,400,110,405, fill = 'white')
window.bind('<a>',left)
window.bind('<d>',right)

ball_formation()

window.mainloop()

error -
if canvas.coords(ball)[0] <= 0 or canvas.coords(ball)[2] >= 800:
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

error shows problem with index in line with canvas.coords(ball) - so first check if you get correct value - it may not have [0] and/or [2]

maybe problem is because you delete ball but code may still try to access it with canvas.coords(ball) - maybe you shouldn't delete it or you should assign None to ball and always check if ball is not None

if you use after() then you don't have to use update()

after needs function's name without () - and later tkinter will use () to run this function - but you have  window.after(300,ball_motion()) and window.after(300,ball_formation())

maybe instead of checking < 0 and running move(..., (0,0)) you should check >= 0 without running move(..., (0,0))

I tried to put ball = none and used global at the very beginning of function ball_motion and it worked properly and also removed window.update, and removed paranthesis I made silly mistake I shouldn't code late night after all

Main problem is that you delete ball but code still runs canvas.coords(ball) which gives empty result
but code tries to get [0] and [2] and this raises error.
When you delete ball then you could set it ball = None
and later always check if ball is not None before you try to do something with ball.
Or you could use other variable ie. ball_exists and set it True (when you create ball) or False (when you delete ball)
and always check if ball_exists before you try to use ball

I see other problem - after needs function's name without ()
but you run after(..., function() ) and this can makes problem.
Other problem can be how you use keys. Normally there is delay after you press key and before it start repeat it. It could be better to use bind <KeyPress-a> to set variable move_left = True and <KeyRelease-a> to set variable move_left = False and in ball_motion always check move_left. The same for move_right

Full working code:
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import time

# --- functions ---

def set_left(value):
    global move_left
    
    move_left = value
    
def set_right(value):
    global move_right
    
    move_right = value
    
def ball_formation():
    global ball
    
    ball = canvas.create_oval(150, 150, 170, 170, fill='white')
    # doesn't need update()
    window.after(25, ball_motion)  # function's name without `()`

def ball_motion():
    global score
    global x_velocity  # PEP8: all `global` at the beginning of function
    global y_velocity
    global ball

    # nove paddle
    if move_left:
        if canvas.coords(paddle)[0] >= 0:
            canvas.move(paddle, -15, 0)
    if move_right:
        if canvas.coords(paddle)[2] <= 800:
            canvas.move(paddle, 15,0)

    if ball is not None:     
        bx1, by1, bx2, by2 = canvas.coords(ball)
    
        if bx1 <= 0 or bx2 >= 800:
            x_velocity = - x_velocity
        elif by1 <= 0:
            y_velocity = - y_velocity
        elif by1 >= 500: 
        
            if score > 200 :
                score-= 200
            else:
                score = 0

            score_label.config(text='Score : {}'.format(score))

            canvas.delete(ball)
            print('ball:', ball)
            ball = None  # set None to recognize that ball doesn't exist
            
            # doesn't need update()
            window.after(25, ball_formation)        

        elif collision_of_ball_with_paddle() is True:
            score += 250
            score_label.config(text='Score : {}'.format(score))
        
    if ball is not None:        
        canvas.move(ball, x_velocity, y_velocity)
        window.after(25, ball_motion)       


def collision_of_ball_with_paddle():
    global y_velocity                  

    if ball is not None:
        bx1, by1, bx2, by2 = canvas.coords(ball)
        px1, py1, px2, py2 = canvas.coords(paddle)
        
        if px1 <= bx2 <= px2 and by2 >= 395:                                    
            y_velocity = - y_velocity
            return True
    
    # return `False` when ball doesn't touch paddle, and when ball doesn't exist        
    return False

# --- main ---

ball = None  # set default value at start
score = 0
x_velocity = 10
y_velocity = 10
move_left  = False
move_right = False

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Game')
window.geometry('900x600+135+0')

score_label = tk.Label(window, font=('consolas', 40), text='Score : 0')  # PEP8: without spaces aroung `=` inside `()`
score_label.pack(side='top')

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=500, bg='black')
canvas.pack()

paddle = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 400, 110, 405, fill='white')  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
window.bind('<KeyPress-a>',   lambda event: set_left(True))
window.bind('<KeyRelease-a>', lambda event: set_left(False))
window.bind('<KeyPress-d>',   lambda event: set_right(True))
window.bind('<KeyRelease-d>', lambda event: set_right(False))

ball_formation()

window.mainloop()


PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code

thank you so much you are really so experienced and knowledgeful with python and its logics I will try to learn more from your code
